# how set breakpoints on running process

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I tried to setup debugging in VSCode with MinGW64 on Windows 10, but i can only get a basic setup to work: Launching and debugging an application works just fine. Also setting new breakpoints when the application is currently halted on another one works.

What doesn't work is setting a breakpoint if the application is currently running. This seems to be a [known limitation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug): But the offered solution doesn't work for me. In which terminal am i supposed to press CTRL-C? None of the VSCode terminals where i would assume the application runs in seems to accept the key combination.

As a sidenote: What is the reason for this limitation? 15 year old Borland developer studio can do this.

Comment: You have to attach debugger to the process first! Without it breakpoints can't work.

Comment: Well, it is attached. It has been started from within VSCode and as i said if the breakpoints have been set beforehand, it also works.